# Fail to connect Mongolab with MongodbShell

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mlab

I'm trying to connect the Mongo shell with Mongolab. I am using my mongolab username and password but it is giving an error: "Failed to connect to 54.81.180.188:56789."

My userName and password is correct.

I'm using Windows 8.1

When I ping  `ds0-----.mongolab.com` that's working fine.

```
     C:\mongodb\bin>mongo ds0----.mongolab.com:56789/dbname -u "MyUserName" -p "MyPassword"
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.3
connecting to: ds027751.mongolab.com:56789/dbname
2015-06-05T10:55:30.019+0530 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 54.81.180.188:56789, reason: errno:10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
2015-06-05T10:55:30.024+0530 E QUERY    Error: couldn't connect to server ds027751.mongolab.com:56789 (54.81.180.188), connection attempt failed
    at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:181:14)
    at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:181
exception: connect failed
```

Comment: did you ever get this fixed? I'm having the same issue

Comment: @pneumee The link you've given does not seem to be working. Can you please update it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, my server abruptly lost the ability to connect to MongoLab. I contacted support, who sent this reply:

> Hello,
>
> Your Experimental Sandbox plan is running MongoDB 3.0.x, which
>   includes changes to Mongo's authentication mechanism. This new
>   mechanism is supported by certain newer driver versions, as described
>   at
>   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.0-scram/#upgrade-drivers.
>
> To connect to this database, you will need to use one of the drivers
>   listed at the above link.
>
> Please let us know if you have questions about this.
>
> Sincerely, Samson

I assume I was upgraded automatically, as I hadn't touched the server code or MongoLab in months. As an immediate fix, I just created a new db in MongoLab, which was created in mongod v2.6.9 (I don't remember seeing an option to choose the version).