# Mongolab and Mongoose Not connecting

Tags: node.js, bash, mongodb, mongoose, mlab

```
So on Sep 30 2015 MongoLab has updated their MongoDB to version 3.0.6.
```

They have been sending out emails about this for some time. stating "

You must ensure that your free Sandbox databases running 2.6 meet the upgrade requirements for 3.0 which includes a list of MongoDB 3.0-compatible drivers. If you do not upgrade your app to a 3.0-compatible driver before this upgrade, you may be unable to connect to your deployment

We are running the latest version of mongoose but still getting an error

```
MongoError: auth failed
```

or this error trying to connect

```
{ [MongoError: auth failed] name: 'MongoError', ok: 0, errmsg: 'auth failed', code: 18 }
```

I have updated to the latest NPM of mongodb, mongoose, I don't understand what drivers need to be updated

FYI I have run

```
sudo npm install mongoose
sudo npm install mongo
```

still no luck

Also I did a new brew install of mongodb and it works from bash connecting to mongolab

when i run mongoose in bash

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect("mongodb://XXX:XXX@XXX.mongolab.com:XXX/XXX");  //X'ed out user name and password and db
```

I get this Response:

```
MongoError: auth failed
    at Object.toError (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/utils.js:114:11)
    at /app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1156:31
    at bound (domain.js:250:14)
    at runBound (domain.js:263:12)
    at /app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1890:9
    at bound (domain.js:250:14)
    at runBound (domain.js:263:12)
    at Server.Base._callHandler (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:448:41)
    at /app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:481:18
    at MongoReply.parseBody (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/responses/mongo_reply.js:68:5)
```

Any Help Would be much appreciated

Comment: Is this your same issue?

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32886832/heroku-app-crashes-after-mongodb-updated-to-3-0)


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32886832/heroku-app-crashes-after-mongodb-updated-to-3-0

Comment: I would tend to agree with @gwitwer as you likely have "pinned" dependencies in your `package.json` though  you are specifically being asked to upgrade the driver.

Comment: wait so when i do an npm install mongoose dose it check my package.json and download that version or the latest