# Node.js Fail to connect to mongodb 3 from Heroku to Mongolab : SCRAM-SHA-1

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose, mlab

MongoLab recently updated the mongoDb version to 3.x. To try to reproduce the environment, i updated my local version of node.js to 4.x, mongodb to 3.x and mongoose to 3.8.

In my local environment i'm able to connect to mongoDb but in heroku i can't.
The following error occurs :

> fail to connect to mongodb for address mongodb://user:password@host:port/dbname

I suspect an older version of mongoose, or a bad connection way, but why it works on my local environment?
Here how i connect node to mongoDb :

```
var uriString = process.env.MONGOLAB_URI || process.env.MONGOHQ_URL
mongoose.connect(uriString, function (err, res) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('fail to connect to mongodb for address ' +       uriString);
    } else {
        console.log('Connection to mongodb ok');
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the actual error your app is generating?

Comment: like i said : fail to connect to mongodb for address mongodb://user:password@host:port/dbname

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Heroku app crashes after MongoDB updated to 3.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32886832/heroku-app-crashes-after-mongodb-updated-to-3-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer,

It looks like MongoDB 3.0 is supported in Mongoose 4.0.0: [Like mongodb doc illustrate](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/introducing-version-40-mongoose-nodejs-odm)

So after upgraded mongoose to v4.x i'm now able to connect to mongoDB using SCRAM SHA 1 credentials.