# Node.js MongoError: auth failed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, mlab

I found out my website wasn't working anymore because i can't auth to my mongolab DB.

here is my code (it used to work for months):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://USER:PASSWORD@ds053419.mongolab.com:53419/jobinfest', 
    function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        if (err) { throw err; }
    }
);
```

I have this error:

```
{ [MongoError: auth failed] name: 'MongoError', ok: 0, errmsg: 'auth failed', code: 18 }
```

But i can access the db via mongolab and :

```
mongo ds053419.mongolab.com:53419/jobinfest -u USER -p PASSWORD
```

I tried  to create new users, even a new db. This way of connection seems to not work anymore

Comment: When you connect using mongo  shell , are you able to access / update collections in jobinfest?

Comment: I found this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30924859/unable-to-connect-to-mongolab-getting-mongoerror-auth-failed, this may be help you.

Comment: @Mani Yes I am able to update collection via the shell

Answer (score -2):

In your code be sure you are replacing `USER:PASSWORD` with your actual username and password.

```
    mongodb://USER:PASSWORD@ds053419.mongolab.com:53419/jobinfest
```